# Trying to use setProperty to an Entry in python with appJar module

Tags: python

I'm using **appJar** to create a gui to my py bot.

I'm trying to create readonly Entrys so... **i've tried this**:

```
app.addEntry("ANI")
app.setProperty("ANI",prop=readonly ,value=True)
```

but it's not working...

I need some help with this.

Thank you all.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the program crash? Does it do something you don't expect? Does it throw an error? If so, what error?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `app.disableEntry('ANI')`

See here for more info: http://appjar.info/pythonWidgetOptions/#widget-manipulation